# How to print a generic tree in console?

Tags: java, tree

I have been trying to print out a properly formatted generic tree in console using this `Node` class below. I would normally show my attempt but I just don't even know where to start. Could anybody give me some pointers on how I could approach this?

```
class Node{
  public String letter;
  public Node parent;
  public Map<String, Node> connections = new LinkedHashMap<String, Node>();
  
  public Node(String letter, Node parent){ 
     this.letter = letter; 
     this.parent = parent; 
  }
  
  public int getChildrenCount(){ return connections.size(); }
  
  public ArrayList<Node> getChildren(){
     ArrayList<Node> out = new ArrayList<Node>();
     for(Node node : connections.values()){
        out.add(node);
     }
     return out;
  }
  
  public String toString(){ return letter; }
}
```

I would like the output to look something like this for example:

```
 |--j
 |
 |  |--c
 a--b
 |  |--d
 |
 |     |--g
 |  |--f 
 |--e
    |--h
       |--i
```

Comment: *Pointer:* Show us (int the question) what you expect the output to look like. If you don't even know what you're trying to accomplish, you'll never succeed.

Comment: So, we can use the exact same rules as you used when writing it down manually, and instead turn them into nested loops. Use a pen and paper to sketch all the rules, then each line can be printed like so `System.out.println(optionalPipe + space + pipe + dash + value);` and the only thing left to do is work out how long the space needs to be.

Comment: @sorifiend Would you mind elaborating a bit? I was assuming this would need to be done using recursion, but regardless of that I am having lots of trouble attempting to put these rules into code.

Comment: Correct, recursion is a good option. First, get a simple tree working in a downwards flow only, then once you have that working you can start using even and odd numbers to have nodes spread up and down the console from the central point.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is possible, but very difficult to implement intelligently, because it will need to make spacing decisions to avoid overlap. A trivial solution for deciphering trees is something like:

```
public String toString() { 
 String s = letter + "(";
 for (Node n : connections.keySet()) {
  s += n.toString() + ",";
 }
 return s + ")";
}
```

**If you need it formatted how you show** (edit):

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map;

public String toString() { 
 findAsString();
 ArrayList<String> lines = map.get(this.letter);
 for (String l : lines) {
  System.out.println(l); 
 }
}

public String findAsString() { 
 map = new HashMap<>(); 
 for (Node n : connections.keySet()) {
  findAsString(n); 
 }
 ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(); 
 for (Node n : connections.keySet()) {
  ArrayList<String> nodeLines = map.get(n.letter);
  for (String s : nodeLines) {
   // CONFIGURE THIS PREFIX to include the letter itself, and needed lines
   String prefix = "|  "; 
   lines.add(prefix + s); 
  }
  lines.add("");
 }
 if (nodeLines.size() == 0) {
  lines.add("|--" + this.letter); 
 }
 map.put(this.letter, lines);
}
```